# How to use $watchgroup or $watchCollection on 2 variable out of which one is array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If we have 2 variable then we can use $watchCollection or $watchgroup as shown below.

```
$scope.firstPlanet = 'Earth';
$scope.secondPlanet = 'Mars';

$scope.$watchCollection('[firstPlanet, secondPlanet]', function(newValues){
  console.log('*** Watched has been fired. ***');
  console.log('New Planets :', newValues[0], newValues[1]);
});
```

How can we use $watchCollection if

```
$scope.myPlanet = 'Earth';  
$scope.otherPlanet = ['Venus','Jupiter','Mars'];
```

and how to access the each variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the same,

```
 $scope.$watchGroup(['myPlanet', 'otherPlanet'], function(newVals, oldVals, scope) {
    $log.log(newVals, oldVals, scope);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/cm0cc3ss/)**

Comment: can I use this to use new values of otherPlanet variable............        console.log(newVals[1][1]); to access 'Jupiter'